# Modify global variable from loop

Tags: linux, bash

Why do I get

```
/tmp/test: line 4: 0=Done: command not found
```

from the below

```
a="0"

while [ true ]; do
  $a="Done"
  exit
done

echo $a
```

I were expecting it would output `Done`.

Comment: You should use `break` to exit a loop.  `exit` will exit the whole shell.

Comment: Why you need a `while [ true ]` loop at all if you have an unconditional `break` or `exit`?

Comment: @Alfe That solved it. Could you post that as an answer?

Comment: Why test the string "`true`" when you could just execute the `true` command (i.e. `while true; do ...; done`).  Not that there's any point in a loop with unconditional `break`, but...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use the `$` when *defining* a variable, only when you are accessing it.

You'll need to change the line defining the variable `a` to:

```
a="Done"
```

---

As to an explanation, what I believe is happening here is that `$a` is being resolved to `0` and then the shell is seeing the entire `0=Done` as a single (unfound) command. Accessing undefined variables still returns a `0` exit code.

Comment: If I do that, then it doesn't print anything. @Alfe's comment is the solition.

Comment: Yes this would have been the next issue :) My answer handles the error you reported in your original post.